# log4j2 no entries in log file

Tags: java, log4j2

When I run my code, the log file is produced but there are no entries.
What am I doing wrong?

In java, I instantiate the logger like so:

```
static Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();
```

Here is my properties file:

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig
dest = C:\\Logs\\cds_import_logs\\cs_import.log
#Make sure to change log file path as per your need
property.filename = C:\\Logs\\cds_import_logs\\cs_import.log

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = all

appenders = rolling

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

loggers = rolling

#Make sure to change the package structure as per your application
logger.rolling.name = com.howtodoinjava
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
static Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();
```

to

```
static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class.getName());
```

I tested it and it works.

Also, make sure that you have your correct package name (not com.howtotodoinjava) in the below line:

```
logger.rolling.name = com.howtodoinjava
```

Comment: logger.rolling.name is pointing to what? the package the calling file is in?

Comment: @MichaelClayton yes

Comment: Ok, that works, but the problem is I only 1 entry in the log file. The 1 entry is getting overwritten.

Comment: @MichaelClayton You're probably missing `appender.rolling.Append = true`.

Comment: @MichaelClayton i had the same issue for the 1st time, id ont know why. But I deleted the log file manually once and re-ran the program and  that solved my issue.

Comment: @notyou thats not required

Comment: my problem is a bit more...I am getting a new log file named "debug-backup....." like every minute. the main log file "cs_import.log" has one entry in it.

Comment: @MichaelClayton See "Configuration with Properties" section in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html. I don't know how you want to configure it exactly